# Reverse-enginering communication protocol

Tags: python, serialization, reverse-engineering

What serialization format is this, and are there any libraries to parse it back to python-native data structures or at least something easier to manage?

At least it looks like it could have a 1:1 correspondent in python.

```
%xt%tableFameUpdate%-1%{"season":[1.329534083671E9,"160",53255],"leaderboard":[["1001:6587656216929005792","1718","Kjeld","http:/..."],["1001:6301086609221020111","802","Asti","http://..."],["1018:995158152656680513","419","QiZOra","http://..."],["1018:8494206166685317681","364","Bingay","http://..."],["1:100000380528383","160","...","http://..."]],"multipliers":{"1001:6835768553933918921":67,"1001:4106589374707547411":0,"1001:5353968490097996024":0,"1018:1168770734837476224":0,"1018:8374571792147098127":0,"1001:4225536539330822139":0,"1:100000380528383":0,"1001:4082457720357735190":68,"1001:1650191466786177826":0,"1001:4299232509980238095":38,"1001:7604050184057349633":0,"1001:6587656216929005792":0,"1001:3852516077423175846":0,"1001:888471333619738847":9,"1001:7823244004315560346":0,"1001:7665905871463311833":0,"1001:4453073160237910447":0,"1001:6338802281112620503":64,"1001:7644306056081384910":13,"1001:4956919992342871722":0,"1001:4126528826861913228":29,"1001:7325864606573096759":47,"1001:6494182198787618518":16,"1001:3678910058012926187":4,"1001:435065490460532259":39,"1001:5366593356123167358":0,"1001:6041488907938219046":8,"1001:6051083835382544277":5,"1001:9187877490300372546":0,"1001:482518425014054339":0}}%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you strip off the first piece and the last percent sign it is json, which you could parse with any json parser. It looks like its using the percent signs as a sort of iterator, you could prolly split on those.

Comment: Lol, how haven't I realized that? Thanks, I'll give it a shot and test it on real data. I'll be back.

Comment: lol, prolly had too long a day, i know that feeling. Many times i've fallen asleep working a problem or left work frustrated, only to come back the next day and figure it out in two seconds lol.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the few characters at the beginning, this looks like JSON.

`%xt%tableFameUpdate%-1%` is not JSON, but the rest is. There's a lot of JSON parsers for python, pick one and it should parse your data without a hitch.